# Screen recording is missing from security&privacy in macOS

Tags: macos, security, macros, privacy

today I was trying to test teamviewer and found out that my option to disable/enable screen recording is missing. (see picture)

[image]

I have tried to reboot and not help. googling around did not come up with any useful info either.

My OS : 10.14.6

Anyone please help?

Comment: Have you checked https://askdifferent.com ?

Comment: @K7AAY i googled, did not come up with anything helpful, but i will post a question there too

Comment: https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/How-to-control-a-Mac-running-macOS-10-14-or-higher/ta-p/44699#toc-hId--**Please%20do%20not%20post%20TeamViewer%20IDs**

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was cross-posted to ask different & already has an answer there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out that only 10.15 has screensharing recording opition. it's a new feature in catalina